# "Под леопарда". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Речь идет о расцветке ткани: "рубашка "под леопарда" - нужно ли "под леопарда" брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не думаю, что нужны. Хотя кавычки зачастую дело весьма субъективное, но тут, вроде, всё ясно.
Если она действительно под леопарда (т.е. расцветка напоминает шкуру животного), то кавычки не нужны. Если это шутка и леопардом назвали драную кошку, то, возможно, кавычки бы и пригодились.